# javadoc: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute

Tags: eclipse, ant, uri, javadoc

I'm attempting to use an Eclipse generated ant file to create JavaDoc for a project.

In the export process I specified that the JavaDoc for a jar I'm using is on disk, so it added this to my javadoc:

```
<link href = "jar:file:/Users/GregD/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.6/httpcore-4.4.6-javadoc.jar!/"/>
```

Running ant against it gets:

```
[javadoc] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not absolute
```

How do I turn this into a URI the Java 8 javadoc tool will honor?

Comment: Try an additional / after file: .

Comment: Changing to    <link href = "jar:file://Users/GregD/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.6/httpcore-4.4.6-javadoc.jar!/"/> got the same error

Comment: @nitind Changing link to <link href = "jar:file://Users/GregD/.m2/repository/org/apache/httpcomponents/httpcore/4.4.6/httpcore-4.4.6-javadoc.jar!/"/> got the same error

Comment: Is the exclamation mark after `.jar` intentional?

Comment: [javadoc] Link href "jar:file://Users/GregD/Documents/workspace/gwt/gwt-visualization-1.1.2/gwt-visualization-javadoc.jar" is not a valid url - skipping link
So yes, it's intentional

Answer (score 0):

An [URI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier) comprises of `scheme://authority/path?...`. So, if using a file scheme on Windows it's usually:

```
file://localhost/C:/Users/GregD/...
```

or

```
file:///C:/Users/GregD/...
```

Note that this in a `<link href=...>` is not going to work for Non-Windows users, of course.